# Remove White Space above and below Seaborn Heatmap Streamlit

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, streamlit

I am generating heatmap in seaborn and displaying it on a Streamlit dashboard. The generated image has a lot of whitespaces above and below.

```
#creating heatmap
df= df[['x','y','z']]

df_temp =  df.pivot_table(index=x,
                      columns=y,
                      values= z)
                    

plt.figure(figsize=(13, 80))
clr = sns.color_palette("RdBu", 7)

ax = sns.heatmap(df_temp, annot=True, fmt='.1f',cmap=clr, cbar=False);

#set x axis label on top
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

# split axes of heatmap to put colorbar
ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

# define size and padding of axes for colorbar
cax = ax_divider.append_axes('top', size = '0.2%', pad = '1%')

# make colorbar for heatmap. 
# Heatmap returns an axes obj but you need to get a mappable obj (get_children)
colorbar(ax.get_children()[0], cax = cax, orientation = 'horizontal')

# locate colorbar ticks
cax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

**Image output**

[image: Image with space on top of chart]

I use st.pyplot to render this on Streamlit dashbaord

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S it displays correctly in Jupyter notebook

Comment: you are setting your image to be 80 inches high. That space has to be filled with something. What is your expected outcome here? That the heatmap stretches to fill that whitespace? Or that that figure is cropped to more sensibly fit the heatmap?

Comment: @tmdavison would like the heatmap to fill the whitespace. i.e heatmap should start right below the top blue bar. The heatmap has about 100 rows. The picture I've added is a cropped version of it.

Comment: if you store a reference to your figure `fig = plt.figure(...)`, then you can use `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.99, bottom=0.02)` to adjust the whitespace. Adjust those numbers to suit your needs